# Joi validation library for node: A field is required when another is not present

Tags: node.js, joi

My schema has some 3 fields that have several conditions depending who is present:

1. **successUrl** cannot be present without ** failUrl** (the same goes the other way around)
2. **responseUrl** cannot be present if **succesUrl** and/or **failUrl** is present
3. In the schema the pair **successUrl** and **failUrl** must be present if **responseUrl** is not (the same goes the other way around)

I managed to make the first 2 conditions to work, but the "when" method that is supposed to make **responseUrl** required when **successUrl** do not exist is ignored for some reason, so the schema validates when there is no successUrl, failUrl and responseUrl which violates my third condition.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    transaction: Joi.string().max(60),
    partner: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/, 'Invalid partner ID').required(),
    amount: Joi.number().min(1).required(),
    responseUrl: Joi.string().uri().when('successUrl', { is: !Joi.exist(), then: Joi.string().uri().required() }),
    successUrl: Joi.string().uri(),
    failUrl: Joi.string().uri()
}).with('successUrl', 'failUrl').with('failUrl', 'successUrl').without('responseUrl', 'successUrl').without('responseUrl', 'failUrl');
```

I'm clearly using it wrong, link to [reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.4.0/API.md#anywhencondition-options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to fix your schema using just [`.and()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.4.0/API.md#objectandpeers) and [`.without()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.4.0/API.md#objectwithoutkey-peers).

The following simplified version of your schema works:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    failUrl: Joi.string(),
    responseUrl: Joi.string(),
    successUrl: Joi.string()
})
    .or('failUrl', 'responseUrl', 'successUrl')
    .and('successUrl', 'failUrl')
    .without('responseUrl', [ 'successUrl', 'failUrl' ]);
```

The `.or()` forces the presence of at least one of the URLs. The `.and()` is to strictly require both or none of the keys inside. The `.without()` is to only allow a key when other keys aren't in the object.

Comment: I think it will not work, since there is no condition that checks for "no responseUrl and no successUrl and no failUrl". .AND checks for successUrl with failUrl or NONE (lets say none), so it pass, then the .WHITOUT says if the is responseUrl there cannot be successUrl OR failUrl, lets say there is no responseUrl, so it pass again.

Comment: @DomingoSL Okay, this requirement wasn't clear from your question. I've updated my answer to include a `.or()` which should satisfy that condition.